# How to specify database configuration in CakePHP 2.0.2?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I've just installed CakePHP 2.0.2 for use in a new project. I'm trying to use a database configuration called `development` but my model doesn't seem to be picking it up.

Based on CakePHP 2's new directory and file name conventions, I've created the following at `/app/Model/AppModel.php`:

```
<?php
class AppModel extends Model {

    public $useDbConfig = 'development';
}
```

However, the default home page tells me:

> Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.

Yet if I change the configuration name in `/app/Config/database.php` to `default` the message changes to a success message, as though it's not picking up my custom `AppModel` class.

How can I remedy this? As the new CakePHP 2.0 docs say to use the `$useDbConfig` property as I have done above?

EDIT: Contents of `/app/Config/database.php`:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $development = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'cakephp_db',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you show your database.php?

Comment: Sure. I've edited the question to show the file's contents now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database configuration is very likely correct.

The reason "Cake is NOT able to connect to the database." is shown, is because the script  that checks whether it can connect to the database (`/lib/Cake/View/Pages/home.ctp`) only uses the `default` database connection for this test. And as there is no such connection, it fails.

Comment: Yup. I can confirm this is the case. Even though the default index page reported CakePHP could not connect to my database, other controllers were able to access and return data fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Like dhofstet has explained, you still need to have a default config. What I do is add a constructor to the DATABASE_CONFIG class to switch between database configs.

Something like this...

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (DEV_SERVER) {
        $this->default = $this->development;
    } else {
        $this->default = $this->production;
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this information, maybe it's what I'm looking for. This works for which cakephp # ? And also do you use this in the database.php ?

Comment: @zeflex It works in versions 1 and 2. Yes, this goes within the DATABASE_CONFIG class in the Config/database.php file.